# vb.net form2 textbox.text to frmPersons mdiparent textbox

Tags: vb.net

I have frmPerson as mdiparent then I have form2 which the form2 has textbox.text

How do i copy the textbox.text of form2 to frmPerson which is a mdiparent

here is my declaration of mdiparent

```
    Dim frmPersons As New frmPersons()
    'Set the Parent Form of the Child window.
    frmPersons.MdiParent = Me
    'Display the new form.
    frmPersons.Show()
```

here is the normal form2 which has a button event
        frmPersons.TextBox1.Text = form2.TextBox1.text

when i click the button from form2, the textbox1.text of frmPerson has no effect
it didnt copy the content from form2 to frmPersons form

What should i do? thank u in advance

Answer (score 0):

On your Form2's button click event... You shouldn't refer to the name of the form you're in, you should do it like this...

```
frmPersons.TextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox1.text
frmPersons.Refresh()
```

Or just simply...

```
frmPersons.TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.text
frmPersons.Refresh()
```

Comment: your answer is right but parent form is an active mdiparent

Comment: What do you mean "is an active mdiparent"? Like it's in modal mode?

Comment: I edited the code so the whole form can do a redraw, it might work.

Comment: the frmPersons is declared as mdiparent = me

Comment: Can you try to post a screenshot of your forms?